# Bootstrap Centered (and Fixed) Navigation Bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I have a simple question. I would like to modify the template here http://bootswatch.com/cosmo/ in order to have the navigation bar centered. As you can see in the example, the navigation starts right at the left of the container. insead I would like to harmonously spread over the whole width of the container... AND to be fixed when I scroll down the page...

Do you have any idea ? what should I modify in the css ?
Many thanks!!

Comment: please accept answers to spread the knowledge to others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this want you are looking for: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3eG7J/1/

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar .nav {
   float: none;
}

.navbar .nav>li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

`.navbar .nav>li` width depend on how many menu items you have.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have a question thou... The problem is that I do not display the page as in your example, but I embed all the content into a centered container, which allows me to provide a nice background image. If I use your code, the navbar takes all the width of the page, and instead I would like to spread over the width of the container...